# In Objective-c blocks, do I need to pass weak/strong self to helpers?

Tags: objective-c

Within blocks, do I need to pass some version of self to helper methods?

In this example, publicMethod() is calling _privateHelper using strongSelf.

But, _privateHelper() is calling _secondPrivateHelper() using self. Is this fine or should I pass down `strongSelf` to the helpers?

```
 - (void)publicMethod
{
     auto __weak weakSelf = self;
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        auto __strong strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) {
           return;
        }
        [strongSelf _privateHelper];
     });
}

 - (void)_privateHelper
{
    [self _secondPrivateHelper]; // <-- what version of `self` is sending the message here? I'm assuming the copied `strongSelf` from above.
}

 - (void)_secondPrivateHelper
{
    NSLog(@"Hello, World");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

When to use `strong` or `weak` depends on how you use the block. In your code `strong` and `weak` does not really matter but I will give an example where it matters and explain how to then use `weak`.

I think you are considering the wrong things here. In your example all pointers to `self` can (and should) be `strong`. You do not need to *dance the dance* here and you should consider using `weak` only when you create *retain cycles* which I will discuss in a moment.

In your case note that when you are inside the block you want a `strong` pointer to `self`. If you have a `weak` pointer the block becomes superfluous when `self` is `nil`. To get a strong pointer simply change your block to

```
... ^{
        [self _privateHelper];
     });
```

rather than the way you do it. Now (and in your original code) you have (and should have) a `strong` pointer to `self` inside both your `_privateHelper` and `_secondPrivateHelper`.

But this is not the issue.

**Retain cycle**

Suppose you have an ivar

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) void ( ^ block )( void );
```

Only now do you have potential trouble and you probably need to use `weak` pointers. The reason being that if somewhere in your code you have

```
self.block = ^{ [self _privateHelper]; };
```

the block will retain a `strong` pointer to `self`. At the same time, `self` is keeping, through the ivar, a `strong` pointer on the block. Can you see the retain cycle? Neither the block nor `self` will ever be released automatically as both are keeping `strong` references to the other.

**Fixing it**

You can change the ivar to `weak` in which case you break the cycle. If the block goes out of scope the `weak` ivar goes to `nil` and there is no retain on `self`.

You could also do

```
self.block = ^ { [weakSelf _privateHelper]; };
```

inside the block to break the cycle. Now if `self` goes out of scope the block no longer has a hold on it and again there is no retain cycle on `self`.

Both these fixes are used - a lot of ivars will be `weak` in a UI environment to prevent the e.g. label keeping a `strong` reference on the vc while the vc also keeps a `strong` reference on the label.

When working with blocks you typically use `weak` pointers to `self` inside the block only if you potentially have a retain cycle. This is often not an issue and in your code also is not an issue as `self` does not retain the block. So in general your helper blocks could probably get away with `strong` pointers to `self`. You only need to *dance the dance* if somehow `self` and the block are creating a retain cycle.

Finally, a third way to fix it is to set the ivar to `nil` yourself. So you could have code that looks like this

```
if ( self.block )
{
  self.block (); // Execute block
  self.block = nil;
}
```

This also makes sense sometimes e.g. when you want to retain the block and `self` until the block executes. Here you release the ivar manually by setting it to `nil` after which it no longer retains `self` and the cycle is broken albeit manually.

You could even do this *inside* the block, e.g. change the block to

```
self.block = ^ { [self _privateHelper]; self.block = nil; /* release when done */ };
```